# High latency in network access on mobile broadband

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, throttling

[First post.](https://superuser.com/questions/889057/is-packet-loss-in-traceroute-a-sign-of-speed-throttling)

I have been using a mobile broadband (HSDPA) connection for the past 2 years. Recently, the ISP started throttling speeds, but the issue was fixed after sometime. However, now the connectivity is pathetic. **It takes a long time to establish a connection** to a website. I have been experiencing this for the past 1 month. It takes 10-20 seconds to load a webpage.

The USB modem (Huawei E303c) constantly keeps switching between the HSDPA and WCDMA mode(which is quite normal with other networks too). Whenever I need the modem to switch back to HSDPA, it takes a lot of time. This is not a modem issue as I have tried other netoworks in the area which are performing well. This is not a signal issue. I get about -75dBm of signal strength, which is pretty decent. I am measuring speeds using [Speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/). Here's a recent result :

[image: Bandwidth result]

As you can see, the upload speeds are pathetic. This is not a local network congestion issue, as it does not vary with the time of the day. Ping stats :

> --- google.com ping statistics ---
>
> 104 packets transmitted, 97 received, **6% packet loss**, time 104489ms
>
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 269.872/942.538/3757.755/690.849 ms, pipe 4

The traceroute has been posted in the first post, linked at the top of the post.

What can be the issue with the network? Is there something else I am missing here that needs to be taken care of?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Your tracerouter shows that there is about 79% packet loss at one of the nodes in your ISP's network. That explains high ping time.

High packet loss leads to low throughout, as packets being sent to you get dropped or the ack sent from you gets dropped. In both cases your packet will be re-transmitted, which will lead to low overall throughout.

They could be trotelling/rate-limiting but your limited browsing speed is way too less for any 'sane' rate-limiting.

I suspect the node in question is faulty and/or over-burdened with traffic. Let your ISP know about it but Mahanager Telecom is not exactly known for their prompt support, is it ? All the best.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please read the 2nd [answer](http://superuser.com/a/889090/407794), where David Schwartz points out that the IP is failing at generating proper ICMP errors, which has nothing to do with my bandwidth.